# Why a single quoted template string doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

I'm taking Andrew Mead - Udemy course in Javascript. But I do have a question about the template string that was given on video.

```
return 'A ${percent}% tip on $${total} would be $${tip}'
```

This doesn't work when I'm typing it in vscode. However, for it to work in my vscode, I must type it in as

```
return "A " + percent  + "% tip on $" + total + " would be $" + tip;
```

I have Babel Javascript and Prettier installed but wondering what exactly the cause of this code is not working correctly? Whenever I run the node arguments.js, it prints out as "A ${percent}% tip on $${total} would be $${tip}"

If I do the node arguments.js for the second code, it does print out, "A 20% tip on $60 would be $12"

I want to learn how to get the strings to work in various ways possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to use back tick ` which is located on the top left of the key board. This is different from quotes `'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
return 'A ${percent}% tip on $${total} would be $${tip}'
```

was likely meant to be:

```
return `A ${percent}% tip on $${total} would be $${tip}`
```

Note the use of backticks `` ` `` instead of quotes `'`. They are needed to create a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Thank you, it is my newbie error! :-(